# Angular upgrade from angular 9 to angular 16, after run ng serve get Error: NG0204 and without any more detail error message

Tags: angular16, angular-upgrade

error like this, Any idea what this could be related to?
[here error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYbPs.png)

I guess it's a config issue, but I've tried many methods to no avail.

Comment: Please try to reproduce the error in the dev server for a proper error message and stack trace

Comment: after run ng serve there is no any error in my dev server

Answer (score 0):

Do not directly upgrade to latest level, upgrade step by step

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).